# sending file over tcp between android and pc

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I want to establish a communication between 2 android devices. with a server to client (through a server) methodology. So generally I was thinking sending the file to a server (pc) then fetch the file on server and send to the other device. So I was working the second part, trying to send a file from pc to android. but for some reason the client cannot connecting to server. here is my code;

```
public class TCPServer extends Thread {

public static final int SERVERPORT = 8901;

public static void main() {

    try {
        System.out.println("S: Connecting...");

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        System.out.println("S: Socket Established...");

        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("S: Receiving...");

        ObjectOutputStream put = new ObjectOutputStream(
                client.getOutputStream());

        String s = "adios.wav";
        String str = "C:/";
        String path = str + s;
        System.out.println("The requested file is path: " + path);
        System.out.println("The requested file is : " + s);
        File f = new File(path);
        if (f.isFile()) {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = fis.read(buf, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                put.write(buf, 0, read);
                put.flush();
            }

            System.out.println("File transfered");
            client.close();
            serverSocket.close();
            fis.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("S: Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
}
}
```

And the client;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Socket s = null;
    BufferedInputStream get = null;

    try {
        s = new Socket("192.168.198.1", 8901);
        get = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());

        int u;

        String str = "/mnt/sdcard/ad.wav";
        FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(new File(str));
        byte jj[] = new byte[1024];
        while ((u = get.read(jj, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fs.write(jj, 0, u);
        }
        fs.close();
        System.out.println("File received");
        s.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: are you using an emulator ?

Comment: nope. using an actual device to test. Btw, I don't need 2 devices for now as I'm just tryin to establish a data transfer from PC to android.

Comment: can you post the stack trace so we can see what's the error

Comment: actually I'm not getting any exception as server app hang on at Connecting state. It doesn't pass the Socket Established line. I run the server app then run the android client app and nothing simply happens. Thought there is something wrong with my client code as it doesn't look like tryin to connect to server. Or my server not responding as I want.

Comment: This could be because of :

**1 :  Your client ip is wrong. Please check (192.168.198.1) it from ipconfig**

**2 :  Your port is being used by another application in your computer or in your android please check it as well.**

Comment: well, I forgot to mention that I'm using Connectify to simplify port issues and other stuff. I'm pretty sure the IP and PORT settings work.

Comment: `System.out.println("S: Socket Established...");` Couldn't you see this in your log ?

Comment: 192.168.198.1 looks like a typical router IP to me. You sure it's correct?

Comment: no I can't see that log. I've tested same settings for another project and it worked. so I'm sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the client part will work.

You should do the socket stuff in another thread or in AsyncTask.

***For example:***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        new doitAsync().execute();
    }

   class doitAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer>
   {

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
       {
           if (result == -1)
           {
               System.exit(0);
           }
       }

       @Override
       protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params)
       {
           Socket s = null;
           BufferedInputStream get = null;

           try {
               s = new Socket("192.168.198.1", 8901);
               get = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());

               int u;

               String str = "/mnt/sdcard/ad.wav";
               FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(new File(str));
               byte jj[] = new byte[1024];
               while ((u = get.read(jj, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                   fs.write(jj, 0, u);
               }
               fs.close();
               System.out.println("File received");
               s.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return -1; // failed
           }
           return 0;
       }
```

Also, you may consider the

```
onProgressUpdate()
```

of the asynctask if you want to update a progress bar so the application won't seem frozen.

Comment: I think  it is better to transfer `fs.close();` and `s.close();` to `try-catch` block